# Given clickstream splitin time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, clickstream

I get a clickstream with a fields 
user_id ,
site_id,
datetime - timestamp time of click
Session counts all clicks in the interval of 30 mins

How can I make SQL query with output of

```
user_id    site_id    session_start_time    session_end_time
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help understanding your question better.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: postgresSQL @CaiusJard

Comment: Welcome to SO, Gani!  To get better help, you should read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and then edit your post with the example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so assuming that you're getting some data like

```
userid, siteid, datetime
1,      1,      2000-01-01 00:30
1,      1,      2000-01-01 01:00
1,      2,      2001-01-01 01:00
1,      2,      2001-01-01 01:30
2,      2,      2002-01-01 02:00
2,      2,      2002-01-01 02:30
```

And you're looking to make the date from the previous row be the start, and the date from this row be the end:

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  siteid,
  LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY siteid, userid ORDER BY datetime) as starttime, datetime as endtime 
FROM 
  table

userid, siteid, starttime,        endtime
1,      1,      null,             2000-01-01 00:30
1,      1,      2000-01-01 00:30, 2000-01-01 01:00
1,      2,      null,             2001-01-01 01:00
1,      2,      2001-01-01 01:00, 2001-01-01 01:30
2,      2,      null,             2002-01-01 02:00
2,      2,      2002-01-01 02:00, 2002-01-01 02:30
```

Each date from a particular row x will become the start date for the following row x+1. The partition means that user and site id have their own start/end date. If this isn't intended, adjust the partition

To hide the nulls:

```
WITH cte AS(
 SELECT 
  userid,
  siteid,
  LAG(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY siteid, userid ORDER BY datetime) as starttime, datetime as endtime 
 FROM 
  table
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE starttime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I want to get  userid       siteid     starttime      endtime  `1,      1,      2000-01-01 00:30,   2000-01-01 01:00  1,      1,      2000-01-01 01:00, 2001-01-01 01:30  1,      2,      2001-01-01 01:00,    2001-01-01 01:30`

Comment: Ok so just surround it all with another query havin a where clause where starttime is not null?

Comment: Yes I want the start time to be the first datetime since it would be the first interation(click of a user )

Comment: I added an example of how to use a cte to hide the nulls